# Unable to download debian file immediately after uploading to Artifactory via curl

Tags: debian, artifactory

I have uploaded a debian file using the following command:

```
curl -H -u$ARTIFACTORY_USER:$ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN -XPUT "http://artifactory-url/artifactory/debian/pool/$package;deb.distribution=trusty;deb.component=main;deb.architecture=all" -T $package
```

I am unable to download the file even after 10 mins via `apt-get update && apt-get download $package`. Getting 'unable to locate package'.

When I upload the file via the UI, it becomes available after a minute.
Also when I click re-index, it becomes available after a minute.

I am doing this in our CI pipeline, after uploading to Artifactory I need the artifact to be available in a minute for next step. What should I do in this case? why uploading via curl not indexing the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Debian package to be available to download by apt-get, The repository index must be updated.
When a Debian package is deployed into a local repository, an event to index the relevant sub path of that repository is being added to a queue.
The queue is constantly being worked on by dedicated Debian metadata workers (8 by default, configurable).
This means, once a Debian package has been uploaded, if the queue is empty and a worker is available, it will start handling the event and index the metadata.
The indexing works by creating a lock for an entire distribution path including the repository (`debian-local/dists/xenial`). Once a worker has started to index a specific combination of repository & distribution, another worker won’t start indexing another event for the same path while the lock exists.
10 minutes is considered a long time for the indexing to be completed (should take about 1m). This can happen in a loaded system or when many Debian packages are deployed to the same distribution path.

You can tune the number of workers using the following system property in `artifactory.system.properties`:

```
artifactory.debian.metadata.calculation.workers = 8
```

You can also force a synchronous calculation of metadata for the entire repository by calling the [Calculate Debian Repository Metadata](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CalculateDebianRepositoryMetadata) REST API method.
For more information about Artifactory Debian index calculation tuning and debugging please consult the following [knowledge base article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-debian-repository-metadata-calculation-works/).

Comment: How can we know that reindexing was completed? What happens with a package version that already exists (override)?